# Softlayer createFirmwareUpdateTransaction

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I would like to update all components on each of our vyatta servers in our environement (90+). I would like to do this with an API call n a script, however when I tried to use:

slcli -C USERNAME api-call Hardware_Server createFirmwareUpdateTransaction SERVER-ID

It only rebooted the test system I tried it on.

Is there some extra information I need to add to the command to specify what items (preferably all such as the ipmi and other components) to upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following **slcli** example:

```
slcli call-api Hardware_Server createFirmwareUpdateTransaction --id=179996 1 1 1 1
```

**Where:**

- `“179996”` is the server_id
- "FIRMWARE UPDATES":

  ```
  "upgrade IPMI Firmware" : 1,
  "upgrade RAID Firmware" : 1,
  "upgrade Bios" : 1,
  "upgrade Hard Drive Firmware" : 1
  ```

Also this is a **Rest** example:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/ SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/[Server_ID]/createFirmwareUpdateTransaction
```

Method: POST

```
{
  "parameters": [
    1,
    0,
    1,
    0
  ]
}
```

This is a **python** script:

```
"""
Update the firmware in a BareMetal server

The script makes a single call to SoftLayer_Hardware_Server::createFirmwareUpdateTransaction
method to update the firmware in a bare metal server.

See below for more details

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/createFirmwareUpdateTransaction

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. 
"""
import SoftLayer.API
from pprint import pprint as pp

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# Declare the API client
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
hardwareServerService = client['SoftLayer_Hardware_Server']

# The id of the bare metal server you wish to update the firmware
hardwareId = 100123

"""
The firmware to update
set the values with "1" to update and "0" skip
"""
ipmi = 0
raidController = 1
bios = 0
hardDrive = 0

try:
result = hardwareServerService.createFirmwareUpdateTransaction(ipmi, raidController, bios, hardDrive, id=hardwareId)
pp(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
print("Unable to update the firmware. "
% (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
exit(1)
```

Regards.

Comment: This looks like what I may need. I was wondoring if here is a way to do it from a BASH script (like the command I posted.

I'm wondering if the command:

slcli -C USERNAME api-call Hardware_Server createFirmwareUpdateTransaction SERVER-ID ipmi 1 bios 1 hardDrive 1 raidController 1

Would work?

Comment: Added some examples can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
slcli call-api --id=155392 Hardware_Server createFirmwareUpdateTransaction 1 1 1 1
```

Note: change the "155392" value for the server id you want to update

Regards